# Is it true that PC power supply screws are 'connected' to earthing/grounding pin of the power supply?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, ground

I was watching a YouTube video (I've provided link in the comments) where the user claims that sometimes when we don't have earthing done in our homes or you are using two pin plug in the socket, the PC cabinet gives you mild shock.

He said it's not lethal (it's like the small DC shocks that you get with metal laptops while charging) but it happens because earthing is not working.

**Then he explains why:**

He said screws of PSU are internally connected to the earthing pin of itself. He also showed it using some testing device as shown in the photo below.

[image]

He also said this also true with motherboard screws.

---

**Now I want to know if these are some specific old generation PSUs/Motherboards or it happens in all modern PSUs/Motherboards too?**

If yes (the logic given by him is correct), I wonder why would a manufacturer do that because a lot of homes in India literally don't have any earthing grounding done in their homes. Including mine.

In fact, most homes in rural or small towns don't have any earthing. It doesn't matter you use a 3 pin plug or 2 pin plug. All will work same.

So I wonder if that indeed is true, I think it means when it is plugged in and you touch the PC cabinet, it will give you a strong AC shock. Which would be lethal. Because the screws are always connected to metal PC cabinet. **Even if the PSU is not faulty and all connections are done properly.**

And I somewhat doubt what he said especially when he said it may be mild shock and not lethal (he said this in Hindi). I might have not understood it correctly.

Please correct me if I'm wrong or misunderstood it.

**Given all that, do all modern PSU screws have this kind of intentional earthing connection with PSU earthing pin?**

Comment: Link to the video: https://youtu.be/gm44eo-V19E?t=105

Comment: That is literally the point of the earth pin.

Comment: @Aron of course I'm aware of that. My question is about a 'connection between the screws and this pin.

Comment: no. I mean, literally, the point of the earth pin is to make the default failure mode, what we call an Earth/Ground fault. By connecting the entire shielding to earth, it is very hard for mains voltage to connect to the user. In fact, the lack of an earth for this setup is extremely dangerous. What would normally be a ground fault, would in fact energize the whole case to mains voltage...

Comment: For what's it's worth, what you describe for India is very much _not_ the case in much of the rest of the world. Building a home with no earthing system would be illegal in the U.S., for example (unless maybe it had no electricity at all, but, in practice, that's pretty much never the case.) I think the same would be true in most or all of Europe, though I'm not as familiar with their electrical code requirements.

Comment: @Aron okay. But does it mean if someone doesn't have earthing he can't touch the desktop cabinet/case at all? Because if he did, he is exposed to mains?

I am really curious because if that were true, most people who don't have earthing would have died. Including me. Because we touch it all the time. Don't get me wrong, but I'm just thinking that is the possibility I am seeing or understanding.

Comment: @Vikas You seem to be misunderstanding. The grounding of the case is a FAIL SAFE. The failure to earth the case correctly is what we call FAIL DEADLY. The problem with fail deadly is that you only know it has failed because you died. ***It is the electrical equivalent of driving a car on the highway with your break lines slash.***

Comment: @reirab For what it's worth. I doubt it is legal to wire electricity in India without a properly configured earth. The issue isn't "electrical code requirements" and more of enforcement.

Comment: @Aron okay. I understand it might be lethal one day. But what different would happen on that particular day? Do you mean the PC needs some other fault too? Not just the lack of earthing?

Or you just need to touch it longer / a particular area to get a fatal or very serious shock?

Comment: @Aron regarding earthing in India. In my area, most electricians don't know how to do it. Especially home buildings. And some don't do it to save some money.

I'm sure same story is true for other parts in India where there is no earthing.

Comment: @Vikas. Example. The PSU overheated. Insulation failed on the live wire. The PC continues to work exactly as expected. You touch the PC, you die.

Comment: @Vikas Most electricians not being able to do it does not make it less dangerous. It is VERY simple to set up a ground. Hammer a piece of 2m long piece of rebar into the ground. Attach the rebar via a wire to the earth pin. DONE. It might not be up to code, but that could potentially turn your death trap into an unpleasant tingle...

Comment: @Aron okay. So I think I'm getting the point. So eventually it will happen because of some other malfunction/fault especially about the wire which causes heavy shocks (like you said live wire).

But on ideal situation, like no other fault except there's no grouding, we will get only a D.C. shock right? Which wouldn't be lethal. Maybe that's why usually we here don't get any lethal shocks even without earthing.

Comment: @Aron yeah I think doing earthing manually would be not that difficult. But still I will need an expert electrician to test it properly so I don't risk it by doing it incorrectly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136361/discussion-between-aron-and-vikas).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes it is true.

The mains inlet connector earth/ground pin is connected to the ATX power supply metal case inside the power supply.

This will also connect the entire PC metal case to earth/ground when the power supply is mounted correctly in place with screws.

Also the ATX power supply output voltage is earth referenced, as the black wires 0V potential is also connected to metal case in the power supply.

The problem of getting shocks happens when a device which has a mains plug with earth/ground is not connected to earthed/grounded mains socket.

Devices with earth/ground pins usually have a mains input filter to suppress electromagnetic interference. One part of the filter consists of two capacitors, one capacitor from Live to Earth, and another capacitor from Neutral to Earth. Earth connection is needed for the input filter to operate as intended.

Problems happen when the earth/ground of the ATX power supply is left unconnected. The capacitors form a capacitive voltage divider, which means that for a 230 volts AC mains input, the metal case of the PC floats capacitively at 115 volts AC.

While that may sound dangerous, it really isn't, as the capacitors are quite small in capacitance, let's assume they are 2.2 nanofarads. At 50 Hz or 60 Hz mains AC frequency, the impedance of 2.2 nF is quite high, approximately 1.2 megaohms.

So touching the PC metal case, or anything connected to the PC, such as mouse, keyboard, display, etc, the electricity can be felt, but leakage current will be limited to below safe values.

It is a problem is multiple devices such as PC and a display are connected together, as if the display also has a similar filter, it may double the leakage current, and all other devices connected to PC with similar mains filter add up too, so the shock can be quite strong, but not lethal.

It is also a problem if you connect devices together, and their voltages are at different potentials. If you have one grounded device, connecting it will discharge the filter caps and equalize the potential, so it is best that the device has a connector which connects grounds first, so that the potential does not equalize via any data pin.

So yes, you will get shocks from any device that requires to be connected to a grounded outlet but is not connected to a grounded outlet. Even if the device is working properly. It is still connected incorrectly to ungrounded socket.

Some old installations don't have grounded outlets and that is a problem when using new devices that require grounded outlets.

Many devices read in their manuals that they must be connected to an earthed outlet, so basically, if you get shocks, you are using the device in a way that is forbidden by the manual, so that is something you have to deal with if you don't have grounded outlets.

Some laptop power supplies come with ungrounded plug, so they do not need ground. But as these types of power supplies have to work without ground, they may have two issues. Their output is not grounded but floating, so it may float at the power supply switching frequency, and the floating voltage may be quite large, so it might also cause feeling of electricity when touching and emit electromagnetic interference. This is usually prevented by putting a filter cap between mains input and low voltage output, but then as it removes high frequency floating voltage, it causes the output to have capacitive coupling to mains voltage floating, so there may be mains frequency  AC voltage present on the output, just like when ATX supply is left ungrounded.

Comment: Afaik metal casings are almost always connected to ground (and devices with metal casings require a three-prong plug and, obviously, outlet that provides ground). Necessary to prevent the casing from accidentally being on high voltage just because the insulation somewhere rubbed through. Devices with plastic casings may choose to not have a ground connection.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Plenty of equipment exist with metal cases and two prong ungrounded plugs, so simply just the metal case does not require grounded plug. Blu-ray players, AV receivers, set-top boxes are like that, for example.

Comment: Ah, interesting, thanks.

Comment: @Justme, I think the rules depend highly on where you're situated.  Here in the UK for instance, two-wire mains leads are permitted only for double-insulated devices, meaning that pretty much anything with exposed metalwork must be earthed.

Comment: @TobySpeight I don't think UK would suddenly have stricter rules than the rest of Europe. Same two pronged non-earthed metal chassis equipment should be on sale in UK as well, with fixed mains cord or with IEC C7/C8 mains connectors/inlets. So they must be double insulated then if they have metal chassis.

Comment: Yes, they must be double-insulated.  In my house, all the double-insulated devices have plastic casing, but I believe metal housings can be made conformant (probably not as cheaply).

Comment: For electronic items, the metal case is honestly less relevant than the size of the power supply. As power supplies get larger, it gets harder to meet both the EMC requirements and the class 2 leakage requirements at the same time.

Comment: @Tetsujin I know how UK plugs work. But take a look at any blu-ray player, AV receiver or set top box with metal chassis, and you will find that many don't connect the earth pin, even if if the plug must have it to be able to open safety shutters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So it's clear to me it's intentional and normal.
Doubt 1: Even if you have 'perfect' PC build (except the fact there is no earthing/grounding done in home) it would theoretically give you shock?

Comment: Doubt 2: Would that shock be similar to touching the AC wire (I mean the wire that is lethal to touch)? (I mean the accidents that happen that kill people or at least burn them severely). 

I doubt it because we have always been touching our PC cabinet which of course is metal and there is no earthing done in our home. But I never died!

Comment: To recap, yes, connecting any device that has mains filter caps that requires earthed socket to an unearthed socket will give shocks. No it is not same as touching live wire directly, because current flows through filter caps, they should limit current to safe non-lethal value. Also any device connected to ungrounded computer can give you shocks too from their metal case (keyboards, etc)

Comment: @Justme I'm getting it now. But we are recommended to always have earthing done properly so that in case there is some other fault like PSU malfunctioned or a AC current carrying wire inside PSU became naked and touched the metal somehow, it would obviously be lethal. Because at that time PSU will FAIL to convert AC to DC. Right?

And that is why we need earthing. It would save us in this kind of situation.

Answer (score 4):

This would be a good cross-post to Electrical Engineering!

There is more than meets the eye.

**Answer First**: It is a **reasonable assumption** in most regions of the world and most applications But it is not a strict requirement of ATX or PC Systems. It is theoretically possible to make an isolated Motherboard and ATX PSU system. But I suspect that it would be difficult to make it compliant with *national governing bodies* for **Electromagnetic Interference** (e.g. FCC, EN, CE) and tested by *Nationally Recognized Testing Laboratory* for **Safety** (e.g UL, CE) while being competitive and universally compatible. . Isolated systems, which are common in industrial sectors, are not marketed as generic PC parts, but as custom systems or marketed for specialized applications. .

### Claim #1

> **Contentious Claim #1** There is no ATX et. al or System level specification that dictates that Chassis/Earth and Common must be bonded

[Intel ATX 12V Supply Design Guide](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/guides/single-rail-power-supply-platform-atx12vo-design-guide.pdf)

["ATX Specification" as archived by instructables](https://cdn.instructables.com/ORIG/FS8/5ILB/GU59Z1AT/FS85ILBGU59Z1AT.pdf)

In the latter document, the word "Ground" is mentioned very sparsely, without clear guidelines. "Earth" is not mentioned in the document.

For example, in **Section 3.3.5**, grounding is mentioned in passing in discussion about back panel I/O clearance and paint masking on cases for ***EMI Compliance***. There are useful diagrams of the back panel.

[image]

The former document, an Intel design guideline for ATX Supplies.

In section 8.4 mentions "Earth Fault" as a "Recommended" Catastrophic Failure Protection", something that shouldn't happen if the Power Supply fails.

Intel also describes the conditions for Safety Compliance which mentions "Earth"

[image]

These are not the authoritative documents, but the lack of any specific reference to earthing or grounding leads me to claim #2

### Claim #2

> Contentious Claim #2: Bonding Chassis to Earth and shielding everything is the most expeditious way to comply with electromagnetic interference requirements (**EMI**)

What may not be transparent to you, but the PC world , as an industry, is specified such that *if you build a system following the MFG instructions* and you use **certified parts** your final system **will be compliant with the regulations** in your region.

This is why every ATX Motherboard must come with a back I/O face plate.

This specification is easy to describe but difficult to define.

One aspect of EMI testing, involves radiated emissions, you point an antenna at the system in a shielded room.

> [image]
>
> [source: science direct](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/radiated-emission)

Another key requirement is **Electrostatic Discharge**, where a high voltage spike (1-4KV) is applied to various pins and metal parts of your device/system and it is expected to not respond or recover on its own.

> [image]
>
> Source: https://www.nutwooduk.co.uk/archive/keitharmstrong/emc_testing3.html

As a whole, EMI testing is similar across the world. It is not surprising that a global product like PC and PC components has settled on a common denominator that keeps everything compatible and keeps the regulators happy. PC's are very (radiofrequency-wise) noisy constructions, and following this pattern keeps everything quiet in the neighborhood.

The last aspect is how to reconcile this with safety

### Claim #3

> **Contentious Claim #3** : If you must have chassis bonding to facilitate emissions, and you also must provide a path to electrostatic discharge to ground, then a non-isolated supply **Class I** is the most obvious standard.

Class I supplies require a PE connection, which was already (per claim #2) required to be electrostatic compliant and must be connected to ground for shielding compliance, and thus you see this little symbol on power supplies and systems.

> [image]
>
> source: https://www.idealpower.co.uk/what-are-the-differences-between-iec-power-supply-protection-classes/

The basic difference is that Class I supplies only have a single layer of isolation between the Power circuitry and the chassis, and thus a protective earth path is required for safety, and all metal sufaces must be bonded to protective earth. Subsequent, because it must also be bonded to EMI shields, and the shields are bonded to ground, this is where the connection between Protective earth and Ground is again reinforced, This is then reflected in the test by the **Nationally Recognized Testing Laboratory** which will specify (on a per-region/country basis) the requirements for the relevant label (e.g. UL in NA, CE in Europe, CCC in China)

> [image] [image]
>
> Comparison of Class I and Class II from XPPower https://www.xppower.com/resources/blog/iec-protection-classes-for-power-supplies

Interestingly, the Intel design guideline does mention a power supply feature in section 3.3.2 about the Power On Pin, but does not mention isolation as a requirement for any other pins.

[image]

[image]

A search of "Class II ATX supplies" (with roman numerals, not class 2) shows much fewer options in the standard locations.

This leads to the conclusion

### Conclusion

> **Contentious Conclusion** Universal Compliance with EMI requires using the metal chassis for shielding and safety regulations reinforce the requirement that the chassis must be bonded to earth. The combination leads to the general assumption that the Protective Earth, Chassis/Metal Case, and system"Ground" or "Common"  must be isopotential, in most compliant situations.

Comment: But your claim #1 is not true. The first PDF you linked in chapter 3.5.6 does dictate that chassis and common must be bonded. Normal ATX power supply specs too.